# Distinguishing string contain 1 with string contain 11 in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that is on a form of one or more numbers divided by ", " e.g

```
 "3", "5, 6, 9", "1, 4", "11, 4"
```

I tried to use:

```
`myString.indexOf("1") !=-1
```

but it returns true for invalid data for strings containing 1 and 11. I don't want to return true for string:

```
"11, 4".indexof("1") !=-1
```

I know this make sense to return true but my question is how can I write the function to not return true in this case and return true only if number 1 is on the string ("1, 8").

Comment: `indexOf` returns `-1` when match is not found. Can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I am looking for the presence of number "1" I don't want to return true if it contains number "11".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Detect a boundary?

```
var str  = '"3", "5, 6, 9", 1", 4", "11, 4"';
var find = "1";

var exists = new RegExp("\\b" + find + "\\b").test(str);
```

Comment: Answers like this makes you realize how much we still have to learn. +1

Comment: +1 
I was answering with a regex too. Awesome. Could you please explain to  me why are you checking at the beginning if the string is already 1? Isn't enough the regex only? It should detect also that case using both boundaries

Comment: Yes your right, I was thought it would not match for some reason

Comment: @AlexK. what is ".test" doing? It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined"

Comment: @DoArNa `.test` applies the `RegExp` to `str` and returns true or false depending on if it matches.  Without it, you aren't actually using the regular expression.  Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/2hzgyr3r/

Answer (score 2):

```
if("1,2,3,4,5,6,7".split(",").some(num=>+num===1)) alert("Valid"); //thanks to mhodges
```

or:

```
if("1,2,3,4,5,6,7".split(",").map(num=>+num).indexOf(1)>-1) alert("Valid!");
```

You need to get each number and check that.

```
.split(",") // get an array: ["1","2","3"]
```

then

```
.some(num=>+num===1) // check if one of the array elements is equal to 1 if it is converted to number
```

or

```
.map(num=>+num) // converts strings to numbers, so it removes spaces
.indexOf(1) // get the position of 1
```

Comment: `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7".split(",").some(elem => elem === "1");` -- short-circuits evaluation, no type coercion/mapping necessary

Comment: @mhodges better +elem===1 (cause of spaces), if you want me to add it to my answer, i will do that...

Comment: @mhodges yep. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to return true when the number 1 is present.

So this is the code

**CODE**

```
var a = Thestring.split(',')
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
   if(a[i]=="1")
       return true
 }
 return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
myString.match(/\b1\b/g)
```

The result will be distinct of null if the string contains 1